# Passing symbols, variables and defining functions within functions

Tags: function-construction, scoping, variable-definitions

Moderators state: “You will be brief and straight to the point”, and so do I.

All codes test whether a polynomial is even or odd, using different approaches.

This works:

```
f[x_] := 1/2 (-E^-x + E^x) ; 
Which[
 f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is Even"],
 -f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is Odd"],
 True, Print[f[x], "Nor even, nor odd"]]
```

...but why this does not work?

```
testpol[pol_] :=
 (f[x_] := pol; 
  Which[
   f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is Even"],
   -f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is Odd"],
   True, Print[f[x], "Nor even, nor odd"]]
  )
testpol[1/2 (-E^-x + E^x) ]
```

I know is better practice to use Module, but I still want to know why the previous code don't work. I manage to write something with Module but that arise another question. I wrote this code that worked perfectly fine:

```
polyTest[pol_, var_ : x] := 
 Module[{f},
  f[p_] := (pol /. var -> p);(*substitution line*)
  Which[
   f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is even"],
   -f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is odd"],
   True, Print[f[x], " Nor even, Nor odd"]
   ]]
```

But, how can I rewrite previous code without rule replacement "f [p_]: = (pol /. Var -> p)"? Something like the code bellow:

```
(* this code don't work *)

polyTest[pol_] := 
     Module[{f},
      f[x_] := pol;
      Which[
       f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is even"],
       -f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is odd"],
       True, Print[f[x], " Nor even, Nor odd"]
       ]]
```

I asked something related before but I still need lights over this.

Thank you to all Sensei for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of f in the first case:

```
Definition[f]
f[x_] := 1/2 (-E^-x + E^x)
```

And this is the second case (with testpol):

```
Definition[f]
f[x$_] := 1/2 (-E^-x + E^x)
```

The parameter is renamed, so the same expression is returned for all values. The following actually works:

```
testpol[pol_] := (
  r = pol;
  f[x_] = r;   (* or f[x_]:= Evaluate[r]; *) 
  
  Which[f[x] === f[-x], Print[f[x], " is Even"], -f[x] === f[-x], 
   Print[f[x], " is Odd"], True, Print[f[x], "Nor even, nor odd"]]
  )
testpol[1/2 (-E^-x + E^x)]
```